# Stack one push notification in notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, notificationcenter

In case the user is busy and didn't check his notifications in the notification centre. I don't want my notifications to get stacked. that may lead to removing the app. by user.

Therefore, when a notification receive I want to clear all previous notifications my app. sent and keep only the new one.

**Is that possible?**

> Note: I want to remove them before they got clicked. If one got
>   clicked I can remove them easily in didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Comment: If the user don't check the notification, your app won't know any info about this App. The only option you have is create a web service (synchronized with the push service) where your app can request if some notification was sent, and add the background request (with all limitations Apple has).

Comment: For example: Parse keeps a badge number on server so you can check it and decide if you want to send push or not.